# View Screen And Print Screen is Diverent on Laravel PHP

Tags: php, css, laravel, printing, invoice

This is The Problem Picture

[View Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kq7N.png)

[Print Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG5iu.png)

Why Screen is Diverent, I want All Screen is Same, I search for tutorial and not working on me

I create this for my report Invoice

This is The View Code all in one page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Kwitansi</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <style>
        body{
            font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
            color:#333;
            font-size:12pt;
        }
        .container{
            margin:0 auto;
            width:21cm;
            height:11cm;
            background-size: 8cm;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position-x: 50%;
            background-position-y: 50%;
            background-image: url({{ asset('appy/images/logo2.png')}});
        }
        table{
            width: 20cm;
            height: 10cm;
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        table th, table td{
            width: 5cm;
            border-style: none !important;
        }
        .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
        .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 1em;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
        .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 1em;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
        .tg .tg-pstd{font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif !important;border-color:#000000;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
        .tg .tg-i09r{font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif !important;border-color:#000000;text-align:left;vertical-align:middle}
        .tg .tg-rk7a{font-size:16px;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif !important;text-align:left;vertical-align:middle}
        .tg .tg-rm9j{font-size:12px;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif !important;border-color:#000000;text-align:right;vertical-align:middle}
        .tg-pstd2{text-transform: uppercase;font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif !important;background-color: #e6e6e6;-webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);-moz-transform: skew(-20deg);-o-transform: skew(-20deg);transform: skew(-20deg);}
        .tg-pstd2_1{font-size:20px;width:7cm;height:1cm;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif !important;background-color: #e6e6e6;-webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);-moz-transform: skew(-20deg);-o-transform: skew(-20deg);transform: skew(-20deg);padding:1px 1px !important;}
        .tg-pstd2_2{text-align: center}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="tg" id="print">
            <tr>
                <th class="tg-rk7a" colspan="3">Invoice #{{ $kwitansi->id }}</th>
                <th class="tg-rm9j"><img height="25cm" src="{{ asset('appy/images/PIKSI.jpg') }}" alt=""></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tg-i09r"><u>Received From</u> <br> Telah Diterima Dari</td>
              <td class="tg-i09r" colspan="3">{{ $kwitansi->received }} <br> ..........................................................................................................................</td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-i09r"><u>Received From</u> <br> Telah Diterima Dari</td>
                <td class="tg-i09r" colspan="3">{{ "Rp. ". format_uang($kwitansi->registration) }} <br> ..........................................................................................................................</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tg-i09r"><u>Received From</u> <br> Telah Diterima Dari</td>
              <td class="tg-i09r" colspan="3">{{ "Rp. ". format_uang($kwitansi->course) }} <br> ..........................................................................................................................</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tg-i09r"><u>Received From</u> <br> Telah Diterima Dari</td>
              <td class="tg-i09r" colspan="3">{{ "Rp. ". format_uang($kwitansi->trasnportation) }} <br> ..........................................................................................................................</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tg-pstd"><u>Received From</u> <br> Telah Diterima Dari</td>
              <td class="tg-pstd2" colspan="3"><b>{{ terbilang($kwitansi->sum_rp) }}</b> <br> .....................................................................................................................................................</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tg-pstd"><u>Received From</u> <br> Telah Diterima Dari</td>
              <td class="tg-pstd" colspan="3"><b>{{ $kwitansi->payment }}</b> <br> ..........................................................................................................................</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tg-pstd" colspan="2"><div class="tg-pstd2_1"><b>{{ "Rp. ". format_uang($kwitansi->sum_rp) }}</b></div></td>
              <td class="tg-pstd2_2">
              </td>
              <td class="tg-pstd2_2">
                <div>
                  <p>
                    Bandung, {{ $kwitansi->register_at }} <br>
                    Penerima <br><br><br><br>
                    {{ $kwitansi->received }}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I Use Single Page for it css and js in one page

What is my mistake

Can Help Me Please

Thanks for Helping

Comment: Are the images the same ?

Comment: @johannchopin What Images,  on My Post ?

Comment: @johannchopin or The Background

Comment: The 2 images on your post View Screen and Print Screen